# Laravel whereIn return only item of each

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-in

I have the following Eloquent query

```
Task::whereIn('user_id', [5,6,7,8])
            ->onlyActive()
            ->with('user')
            ->get();
```

which works perfect. The problem is that each `user_id` can have **multiple Tasks**, but i do only want to return **one Task** of each `user_id`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to define a new relationship on User model to get the latest Task - if that works for you

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    public function latestTask()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Task::class)->latest();
    }
}
```

Then to query one active Task for each user

```php
User::whereIn('id', [5,6,7,8])
    ->with(['latestTask' => function($query){
        $query->onlyActive();
    }])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use take()?

```
->with([
   'user' => function($user) {
       $user->tasks()->take(1);
    }
])
```